# Changing a world without losing map made by player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I'm using a new world in my server, I'm losing all map my friends and I made.

I'm good with backuping playerdata, but when I do the same for maps (`world/data/map_XX.dat`), they are not on the new world.

They are a way to use "old" maps on a new world ? Without having to redo all of them, of course.

Comment: Do you actually mean the map items? Because otherwise it's contradictory, you want to use an old map/world "on" a new map/world. If you mean the map items, then it's an interesting question. Have you tried for example creating a new map on the new world and then overwriting that with the one from the old world (which has the same number)? Because otherwise you don't have any reference to it in the new world, no item that actually uses that map ID. I think there's also an internal counter, separate from all inventories and stored maps, that says which map ID to use next when creating a new map.

Comment: I mean map items. Each map is generated with a unique ID, which refere to this specific map. (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Map_item_format)

Comment: I keep inventories when I change the world, so I keep maps items, so I should keep their reference to `.dat` files from the old world? Or I'm wrong ?
Of course, I tried to copy all `map_x.dat` files and then go check an old map, but she was cleared